# How to equalize android button with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER ,namely when I press ENTER to physical keyboard , to click my button?

Tags: android

How to equalize android button with `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`, namely when I press `ENTER` to physical keyboard, to click my button?

```
Button enterBtn;
saveBtn = (Button) findviewbyId(R.id.enter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      switch(keyCode) {
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                             // put your button click code here
        break;
      default:
        return false;
          }
   return true;

        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont want to type text I just want to click the button